# Dynamic Imports with NuxtJS and VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, nuxt.js

I want to create dynamic pages in nuxtjs. My Content is stored in markdown-files located in `content/faq/`. So i need dynamic imports to import the correct file based on the `param.slug` variable. How can i do this?

My `_slug.vue` inside `pages/faq/` looks like this:

```js
<template>
    <no-ssr>
        <Page :title="title" :subtitle="subtitle" :cover="cover" :images="images" :navigation="navItems != undefined" :navItems="navItems" :footnotes="footnotes">
            <div class="mt-8" v-html="body"/>
        </Page>
    </no-ssr>
</template>

<script>
import Page from '../../components/partials/page'
export default {
    layout: 'static',
    components: {
        Page
    },
    asyncData({ params }) {
        let content = () => import(`../../content/faq/${params.slug}.md`).then(content => {
            return {
                body: content.html,
                cover: content.attributes.cover,
                title: content.attributes.title,
                subtitle: content.attributes.subtitle,
                navigation: content.attributes.nav,
                navItems: content.attributes.navItems,
                footnotes: content.attributes.footnotes,
            }   
        })
    },
    data() {
        return {
            images: [],
            imageDescriptions: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        if (process.client) {
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let parsedHTML = parser.parseFromString(content.html, 'text/html');
            for (var i = 0; i < parsedHTML.images.length; i++) {
                this.images.push({ 
                    src: parsedHTML.images[i].src, 
                    description: parsedHTML.getElementsByTagName('em')[i].innerText, 
                    alt: parsedHTML.images[i].alt 
                });
            }
            console.log(this.images);
            for (var i = 0; i < parsedHTML.getElementsByTagName('em').length; i++) {
                this.imageDescriptions.push(parsedHTML.getElementsByTagName('em')[i].innerText);
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

When i open the page `localhost:3000/faq/test` i get the error: `content is not defined` But when I pronit the function `created()`, he can't find all variables ones like `body`, `cover`, `title` and so on...

Why can't he find content and the other variables? Does the import need to be carried out elsewhere?

Comment: I guess `content` that is being complained about is the one in `created()` handler which doesn't have access to `content` variable above and doesn't have a definition of its own

Comment: @Neptune thanks for your answer. What function do you mean, should I use instead so I can access the variable?